Show numbers of related post based on sub category and HIDE parent category
I removed my prev question since I have found the solution and it works as expected.
Here's the code to show numbers of related posts based on sub category (cat child):
<?php       
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach( $categories as $category ){
    if( 0 != $category->parent )
        $child_cat = $category;
}
if(isset($child_cat)){           
    $args = array('cat' => $child_cat->term_id, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 7, 'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()));
    $related = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $related->have_posts() ){
        while( $related->have_posts() ){
            $related->the_post();
            if( 0 != $related->current_post ){
                echo '<div class="main_relp">';
                    echo '<ul class="cur_rpost">';
                        echo '<li>';
                            echo '<div class="relp">';
                                echo '<div class="img_relp">' . the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="title_relp">' . the_title() . '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
?>

However, everytime I change the number (in the code is 7) to others, it always reduce one title. Please tell me why is it. (I'm a beginner in php/wp).
Another question: Is the code above good or bad or let me know the best one. Thanks

where did you get numberposts? The official doc for the parameters WP_Query accepts doesn't mention it https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Query/parse_query/

yes I see the doc in that link. I don't know how to add number of posts, say, 6 posts in related posts based on SUB category :( please help, bro.

<?php       
$categories = get_the_category();
$child_cat = null;

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->parent != 0) {
        $child_cat = $category;
        break; // Stop after finding the first subcategory
    }
}

if ($child_cat) {           
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $child_cat->term_id,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 7, // Correct parameter
        'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())
    );
    $related = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($related->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div class="main_relp"><ul class="cur_rpost">';
        while ($related->have_posts()) {
            $related->the_post();
            echo '<li><div class="relp">';
            echo '<div class="img_relp">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="title_relp">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
            echo '</div></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
?>

Explanation
Removed if( 0 != $related->current_post ) to ensure all posts are displayed.
Changed showposts to posts_per_page for correct parameter usage.
This will now display the correct number of related posts based on the subcategory.
I'd love to hear your feedback on this solution!
Did it solve your issue?
